# How To call class extending ClientRequestFilter for Client-side Filter

Tags: java, rest, filter, jersey, jax-ws

I have a class which implements the ClientRequestFilter for the Client-side filtering.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest;

@Provider
public class checkRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter{

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext clientRequestContext) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("I am in checkResponseFilter");
    }
}
```

But I don't know what to do so that I will be able to call this filter?

Do we need to add some kind of servlets in web.xml ?

Answer (score 8):

A ClientRequestFilter acts on the client side. Thus, you don't have to add it to the servlet, but to the client (assuming you are using Jersey client API).

When you build your client you do something like this:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(new CheckRequestFilter()); // your filter
// more filters
WebTarget target = client.target(....
```

You can find a nice example over here on authentication support:
https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e5464
and this one on filters
https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4391

If you meant to use a filter on the server side, you need to use ContainerRequestFilter.

Comment: Broken link, but I found this example: https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-rest-client-authentication/

Comment: I've seen this registered on either the ClientBuilder or Client.  Does it work in both places?

Comment: yes @Wheezil I guess you mean like in here: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4391

Answer (score 0):

Another option to do this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;

cb = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
client = cb.register(new checkRequestFilter()).build();
```

Also note that this is a client side filter, so you are trying to filter a request (*not a response*) that you send (hence you register the filter on your client).